# Converting spreadsheet into a Javabean

Tags: java, excel, javabeans

I have a spreadsheet that has x amount of rows. Each row has a static set of data. I want to convert this data into a Java bean.

For example, if my row looks like this...

|name|age|

|john|21|

And I have a simple Bean like this...

```
public class Person{

private String name;
private int age;

//standard getters and setters

}
```

What is the best way to convert the spreadsheet to a Java bean? I currently am using hssf to read and write to the sheet, but cannot think of an easy way to create the bean from the spreadsheet.I know I can simply call all the getters / setters based on row and column counts, but there must be a better way, any thoughts?

Comment: http://www.codesandscripts.com/2017/03/converting-excel-file-to-list-of-java-beans.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the [JExcel API](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)

Like this:

```
    public DataReader(File file) {
    this.file = file;
    Workbook workbook;
    try {
        workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
        sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
    } catch (BiffException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void readData() throws ParseException {
    int sheetLength = sheet.getRows();
    System.out.println(sheetLength);

    for (int i = 1; i < sheetLength; i++) {
        String eventTitle = sheet.getRow(i)[22].getContents();
    }
}
```

You can use

```
sheet.getRow()[].getContents();
```

For each column. It will return a String that you can parse for your Bean.

Comment: Seems like a great way to go, but I have to use excel 2010, which this does not support :(

Comment: @Shijima It looks like the latest version may be compatible with Excel 2010. Try downloading version 1.7, and try the simple example in a DataReader class by including the jar in your buildpath and importing into your class.

Comment: Unfortunatly my organization requires I only use approved software from their internal download site. It's not available, +1 for recommending though, that really would have made things easy :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an open source library called jxls, which converts spreadsheet data into java beans http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/reader.html

However, I think it may be easier to write/read your data into XML and then use jaxb to convert XML to java beans.

Answer (score 0):

With [sep4j](https://github.com/chenjianjx/sep4j) you can do it in one line after defining the headers with a HashMap.

```
    Map<String, String> reverseHeaderMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    reverseHeaderMap.put("User Name", "name");  //"User Id" is a column header in the excel.
                            //"name" is the corresponding property of User class.
    reverseHeaderMap.put("Age", "age"); 

    List<User> users = ExcelUtils.parseIgnoringErrors(reverseHeaderMap, inputStream, Person.class);
```

also you need to add a String-based setter for the age property in Person class.

```
    public void setAge(String ageString){           
        this.setAge(Integer.parseInt(ageString));
    }
```